# MapView in Android Google Maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-mapview, android-maps

I added a code from https://gist.github.com/joshdholtz/4522551 to my Android App Project in Eclipse.

In my main activity I added SomeFragment fragment = new SomeFragment(); but the map in my app is still not visible. Only gray grid.

What do I have to do to show the map?

I am using MapView because android:minSdkVersion="8" is a must in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have added your api key correctly in your manifest file.

Also make sure that you have registered your project in your console (in configure key for project),

You can also see this link, may be it helps : http://ucla.jamesyxu.com/?p=287

If you have done all above correctly, and still problem persists, then please post your code for further help...

Comment: What do you mean with "Also make sure that you have registered your project in your console (in configure key for project)"? Here is my project https://github.com/PeterErjavec/Android-Maps.git

Comment: You need to add  `<your-SHA1>;<your-package-name>`  in API access in your google API console for giving access to your application to fetch map. This happened with me also, I was getting grey grids and not the map, the mistake I did was that I added my some other package name, rather than the one which I was using. I am sure you might have checked that. If you haven't, plz check it first. For more detail : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html#maps_key4

Comment: Plz, donot write your SHA1 so openly, remove your previous comment, hide SHA1, its not safe to give it open like this.

Comment: Forgive me if I am wrong, but I think you have added wrongly in your console : `<your-SHA1>;com.exmaple.maps`, in the git repository that you showed me, package name is `com.example.peter.googlemaps`, so plz add `<your-SHA1>;com.example.peter.googlemaps`.

Comment: Also in the manifest you have written : `android:value="@string/google_maps_key"` but I can't see anything in your resources for map keys. It's okay if you have not added to your git repository, but have actually added to your project, but before your run your project, plz remember add your google map keys to this file : `https://github.com/PeterErjavec/Android-Maps/blob/master/app/src/debug/res/values/google_maps_api.xml` and plz donot add google map keys in repository. Keys are kept to be hidden, as they are your secret.

Comment: So sorry mate. I uploaded a wrong project to git. This is the right one https://github.com/PeterErjavec/Maps.git . And I changed the API key. It is in the project. Thank you for your help. Really appriciate.

Comment: This is just a test app for map to get working and I am gone change the key later.